# How can I have two virutalhosts on the same Apache 2.2 server

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, virtualhost, reverse-proxy

I have an Apache 2.2 server with an existing virtual host on it (foo.com) that proxies to an internal server.

I've since add another virtual host to it (bar.com) that I'd like to proxy to a different internal server.

My vhost.conf file looks like this (minus some comments and anonymisation):

```
# START
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://foointernal:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://foointernal:80/
    DocumentRoot "E:/Apache/htdocs/foo/"
    ServerName foo.com
    ServerAlias foo.com
    ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
    ErrorLog "E:/Apache/logs/foo_error.log"
    TransferLog "E:/Apache/logs/foo_ccess.log"
</VirtualHost>    

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://barinternal:80/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://barinternal:80/
    DocumentRoot "E:/Apache/htdocs/bar/"
    ServerName bar.com
    ServerAlias bar.com
    ServerAdmin me@mydomain.com
    ErrorLog "E:/Apache/logs/bar_error.log"
    TransferLog "E:/Apache/logs/bar_access.log"
</VirtualHost>    
# END
```

When I open http://foo.com in a browser, everything works fine. I get the internal server I expect, etc.

When I open http://bar.com in a browser, I get the internal server used by foo.com

It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the Proxy portion, as when I comment out the Proxy* lines `foo` and `bar`'s DocumentRoot's are still cross-wired as well.

Why and how to I convince Apache 2.2 to proxy to the right server?

Comment: This looks like it should work as expected. Did you remember to restart apache ?

Comment: Definitely - the bar*log files also don't get created/populated

Comment: Reversing the entries also gives the same effect, but foo.com shows bar.com instead

Comment: Then that tells us that somethign else is not correctly configured because apache is serving the default vhost - the first configured. Do you have a NameVirtualHost directive correctly configured ?

Comment: Ah ha... someone previously had commented out the NameVirtualHost entry. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config as presented should work. That you only ever get the first vhost delivered suggests that something else not shown is misconfigured.

Check that you have a suitable [`NameVirtualHost`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#namevirtualhost) directive.